# How to get WebElement text only for direct child?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm working with Python Selenium, and in the following HTML structure:

```html
<div>
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
  <div>
    <p>some text <strong>important</strong></p>
    <a>link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the text from each descendant (h2, div, p, strong, a) of the parent div, e.g. for the `<p>` tag I want `some text`.

I've been using the `.text` attribute and getting `some text important` instead. I'd like to use something similar as the BeautifulSoup attribute [.string](https://salmanwahed.github.io/2015/03/31/string-text-difference-bs4/).

Edit: I need the code to work for any parent element containing descendants with more nested descendants - not just this particular HTML structure.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: perhaps add a couple of different examples and indicate the expected result for each one.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Rather than explaining your solution to the problem, explain the main problem you are trying to solve so we can perhaps propose a better solution. As it is, it's not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I've edited my question. Hope it's clearer now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Script executor to return `textContent`.

```
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[contains(.,'Welcome')]/following::div/p")))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something more general. I need in general the code to work for any parent element containing descendants with more nested descendants.

Comment: What do you mean by generic code.can you post some more html and your expected output you are looking after.

Comment: I didn't say 'generic', I said 'general'. That means I need something more flexible. Solution that takes into account different tag names, various number of tags, various structures of the descendant elements.